# Measure time taken for repartitioning of spark structured streaming dataframe

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

I want to do a performance comparison in which I want to measure the time taken in repartitioning of spark structured streaming dataframe.

for eg time taken for the following step

```
df.repartition($"colname")
```

Any ideas how can this be achieved ?

Comment: do you want to measure it for every micro batch, or just once?

Comment: for every micro batch indeed